# Bootstrap Modal is not closing when I using this attributes to my modal Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this attribute to my Modal Id to close the Modal but its not working.
I have tried this solution which I found online but it didn't seem to work.

```
$('#id').attr("data-bs-dismiss", "modal")
$('#id').attr("aria-label", "Close")
```

Comment: I think you have to close the modal my calling bootstrap functions

Comment: If modal id like `id="id"` then you can use `$('#id').modal('hide')` method.

Comment: `$('#modal_name').modal('hide')` to hide